# Photoshop - how to create round borders from straight bands/

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is it possible to create a good/decent quality round border from a straight band?

E.g. if I have a band designs like these:
[image: celtic bands]

Is it possible to transform them into a round border, such as:
[image: celtic borders]

Thank you!

Comment: Illustrator brushes are better for this.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You are using the wrong kind of software. Better to use a vector image editor. This is super easy. Illustrator has brushes, even free software like Inkscape has a Pattern along a Path effect. [See example here](https://imgur.com/a/MZP7cJ9) made in Inkscape in about two minutes.

Comment: Sounds like I'll need to get Illustrator for this, will try that out, thanks to you both!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the POLAR COORDINATES filter.

First, you need to trim the pattern that you with to use to eliminate any white space around the pattern like this:
[image]

Next, go to `Image > Canvas Size` and make the smaller canvas dimension equal to the larger so that the image is now a perfect square:
[image]

Then, go to `Filter > Distort > Polar Coordinates` and select `Rectangular to Polar` :
[image]

The result should look like this:
[image]

As mentioned in the comments above, Photoshop will not necessarily give you the best quality result, so if you need the best possible quality then exploring vector alternatives might be a better option. If you *have* to use Photoshop, start with the highest resolution image that you can get and maybe consider converting the end result to paths.

Comment: I don't think this matches the OP desired result. Sure the pattern is now in a circle, but the examples aren't distorted like that.

Comment: Thanks for this, polar coordinates was my first idea too and yeah as you can see it doesn't look that great, I will explore alternative software, thanks!